# How preserve breakpoints when Meteor scripts change (disable the unique query parameter added to script urls?)

Tags: javascript, meteor, javascript-debugger

Meteor adds a unique hash query parameter to the end of all the script files returned. Which is great except when it comes to debugging. If I set breakpoints in a file I change I have to re-add those breakpoints. Very annoying because I usually have breakpoints in the file I change. I don't mind having to disable caching and force a page refresh to get the new version of the code in cases like this.

If there is another way to preserve breakpoints, this would also solve my problem

Comment: Make the script a static resource in the `/public` directory, reference and put breakpoints in it? Short of that, you could use `console.log()` (which I personally prefer).

Comment: I've never tried it, but try using `debugger` (javascript) where you want the inspection to come about

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions for debugging.

As well as being able to use console.log() you can try http://observatoryjs.com for very detailed live insight into your app.

Many people also use https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector for server side debugging.

To specifically address your question, though, well there is not much you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks. I did know about node-inspector (but others may not) and I did know about observatory (once again others may not). However, I am really looking for debugging on the client side.